# http to https EXCEPT

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, https

I am using this to redirect all requests for http pages to https.  However, I need to exclude certain pages on the site that must remain http.  I am at a loss how to do this.
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.reny.net/$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 0):

Use `RewriteCond` to check `%{REQUEST_URI}` before the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/page1|/page2)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.reny.net/$1 [R,L]
```